# how to upload a picture using Flask, Pyrebase & Firebase - my process doesn't work

Tags: python, firebase, flask, pyrebase

I am creating a short business directory web app with Flask & Firebase; I have managed to store the data collected but I also wanted the user to be able to upload their business photo; with what I have, when I store the photo with `firebase.storage()` I can create a folder and image name as intended, but the file is empty.  I keep trying different things - like where down the line I store the picture file but they all produce the same outcome - either an empty picture file or an error message.

My goal is when a user registers their details (along with uploading their photo), they can then login where they will have their details and their business picture on display.

python file

```
import pyrebase
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)
config = {
    "apiKey": "",
    "authDomain": "",
    "databaseURL": "",
    "projectId": "",
    "storageBucket": "",
    "messagingSenderId": "",
    "appId": "",
    "measurementId": "",
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

auth = firebase.auth()
db = firebase.database()
storage = firebase.storage()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    unsuccessful = 'Please check your credentials'
    successful = 'Login successful'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('name')
        password = request.form.get('pass')
        try:
            user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            registerList = db.child("Bame_Register").child("business").get(user['idToken']).val()
            pic = storage.child("images/new.jpg").get_url(None)
            return render_template('profile.html', registerList=registerList, pic=pic)
        except:
            return render_template('new.html', us=unsuccessful)
    return render_template('new.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    unsuccessful = 'Please check your credentials'
    successful = 'Registraion successful'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('pass')
        userName = request.form.get('inputName')
        businessName = request.form.get('businessName')
        startYear = request.form.get('startYear')
        businessDescription = request.form.get('businessDescription')
        web = request.form.get('web')
        businessNumber = request.form.get('businessNumber')
        businessEmail = request.form.get('businessEmail')
        businessImage = request.files.get('businessImage')
        try:
            user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password) 
            auth.send_email_verification(user['idToken'])
            bameRegister = dict(
                userName = userName,
                businessName = businessName,
                businessStartYear = startYear,
                businessDescription = businessDescription,
                businessURL = web,
                businessNumber = businessNumber,
                businessEmail = businessEmail,
                businessImage = businessImage,
            )
            storage.child("images/new.jpg").put(businessImage, user['idToken'])
            results = db.child("Bame_Register").child("business").update(bameRegister, user['idToken'])
            return render_template('new.html', x=successful)
        except:
            return render_template('new.html', y=unsuccessful)
    return render_template('new.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flask Firebase Auth</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    {% if s %}
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <h2>{{s}}</h2>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if us %}
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <h2>{{us}}</h2>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="/" method="post">
      <h2>Please sign in</h2>
      <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="name"  placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="pass"  placeholder="Password" required>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    {% if x %}
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <h2>{{x}}</h2>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if y %}
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <h2>{{y}}</h2>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="post">
      <h2>Please create an account to register your business</h2>
      <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email"  placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="pass"  placeholder="Password" required><br>
      <label for="inputName">Enter your name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>
      <label for="businessName">Business Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="businessName" name="businessName" placeholder="Business Name" required><br>
      <label for="startYear">Year buisness started:</label>
      <input type="date" id="startYear" name="startYear" placeholder="2019"><br>
      <textarea name="businessDescription" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Describe your business in a few sentences..." required></textarea><br>
      <label for="web">Enter your business website (Optional):</label>
      <input type="text" name="web" id="web" placeholder="Please start with https:// "><br>
      <label for="businessNumber">Buisness number (Optional):</label>
      <input type="number" name="businessNumber" id="businessNumber" placeholder="Enter landline or mobile number.."><br>
      <label for="businessEmail">Buisness email (Optional):</label>
      <input type="email" name="businessEmail" id="businessEmail" placeholder="Enter your business email"><br>
      <label for="business_img">Select image:</label>
      <input type="file" name="businessImage" accept="image/*">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register business</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

profile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>{{ registerList['businessName'] }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ registerList['businessName'] }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ registerList['userName'] }}</h2>
    <div class="">
      <img src="{{ pic }}">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p>Year business started: {{ registerList['businessStartYear'] }}</p>
    <p>{{ registerList['businessDescription']}}</p><br>
    <p>{{ registerList['businessURL'] }}</p>
    <p>{{ registerList['businessEmail'] }}</p>
    <p>{{ registerList['businessNumber'] }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone can help me come up with a solution or point out to me where I'm going wrong that would be very much appreciated & grateful!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you solved the issue ?